# Form's dropdown menu selected items are null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

My problem is very strange. I have a small form which has two drop down menus to select items and create a new item with those two included. Here is the object's most basic values:

```java
    public class Rental {
      private Integer id;
      private Movie movie;
      private Client client;
    }
```

The problem is as follows. My HTML file has this form:

```html
    <h1>Add New Rental</h1>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/rentals/add}" th:object="${rental}" method="post" >
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            <label for="client" class="col-form-label">Client</label> 
            <select class="form-control" th:field="*{client}" id="client">
                <option disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select Client</option>
                <option th:each="clnt : ${listClients}" th:value="${clnt}" th:text="${clnt.name + ' ' + clnt.lastname}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            <label for="movie" class="col-form-label">Movie</label> 
            <select class="form-control" th:field="*{movie}"  id="movie">
                <option disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select Movie</option>
                <option th:each="mov : ${listMovies}" th:value="${mov}" th:text="${mov.title}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=" Submit ">
        </div>
    </form>
```

And the controller that handles this page is as follows:

```java
    @RequestMapping(path = "/rentals", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listRentals(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("rental", new Rental());
        model.addAttribute("listRentals", this.MCRService.getRentals());
        model.addAttribute("listClients", this.MCRService.getClients());
        model.addAttribute("listMovies", this.MCRService.getMovies());
        return "rentals";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rentals/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addRental(@ModelAttribute("rentals") Rental rent) {
        Client client = this.MCRService.getClient(rent.getClient().getId());
        Movie movie = this.MCRService.getMovie(rent.getMovie().getId());

        if (((client.getRentalCollection().size() + 1) * 10) <= client.getBalance()) {
            client.addMovie(movie);
            this.MCRService.updateClient(client);
            this.MCRService.updateMovie(movie);
        }

        return "redirect:/rentals";
    }
```

But when I run this, select both a client and a movie, and I press submit, the console throws a `NullPointerException`, and turns out that the client and the movie are both `null`, which is weird since I'm using the entire object in the selection. What am I doing wrong here? Is it some sort of problem with the `th:value` and `th:field`? Or is my code flawed? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it in this way. The changes to the html were in addding `selectpicker` to the select's class and changing the client's and movie's option for each's value to the id.

```html
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" th:field="*{client}" id="client">
        <option disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select Client</option>
        <option th:each="clnt : ${listClients}" th:value="${clnt.id}" th:text="${clnt.name + ' ' + clnt.lastname}"></option>

    <select class="form-control selectpicker" th:field="*{movie}"  id="movie">
        <option disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select Movie</option>
        <option th:each="mov : ${listMovies}" th:value="${mov.id}" th:text="${mov.title}"></option>
```

The java wasnt modified greatly, but with those three changes, the whole thing works!